# having ImportError that i did not import

Tags: python, html, css, django, bootstrap-4

Please someone should help me out. I did not import ugettext_lazy from anywhere in my project am using django 4.2.1. i just install django-messages from then i cannot proceed with my project. this error keep showing an am stock in one place. I check all my import to see where the ugettext_lazy is comming from but i could not trace it. i even downgrade django 4 to django 3 but i was still having some import error in django 3. i upgrade it again to django 4. please help me out. thanks

this is my views.py imports

```
    # from http.client import HTTPResponse
# from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
 
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, PostForm, CommentForm, NovenaCommentForm
from . models import About_us, My_blog, Like, Comment, Slider, Prayers, Description, Novena, NovenaComment

from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.paginator import Paginator,  EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from . like import new_likes, authmessage
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, auth
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
# from django.contrib import messages
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, DeleteView
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, user_passes_test, permission_required
from authentications.message import infor
```

this is admin imports

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . models import My_blog, Comment,Slider,Prayers,Description,Novena,Like,About_us,NovenaComment,SubscribedUser
```

this is my models.py

```
from email.mime import image
from time import timezone
from turtle import title
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

this is the django_message install in my install_app

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
    'crispy_forms',
    'authentications',
    'django_messages'
]
```

this is the compleate error

```
C:\Users\Christopher\Better_world_blog>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 115, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py",
line 381, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 123, in
create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django_messages\apps.py", line 2, in
<module>
    from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
ImportError: cannot import name 'ugettext_lazy' from 'django.utils.translation' (C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\__init__.py)
```

Comment: this this a serious headache to me. am almost finishing this project and now i cannot move on because of this challenge. please someone should help me out. i keep gazing at my codes to see the the ugettext but could not fine it

Comment: You seem to be using this [package](https://github.com/arneb/django-messages), it's not maintained and hasn't been updated since 3 years. `ugettext_lazy` was deprecated in Django 2.2 and removed in 3.x

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to your project but django it self because `ugettext_lazy` has been removed in Django 4.0 . Just use `gettext_lazy` instead .

possible solution :

in **django-messages** open [field.py](https://github.com/arneb/django-messages/blob/master/django_messages/fields.py) in line 8 change  :

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

**to :** `from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _`

Comment: OP's using a different package, even if they were using this one might as well advice to do away with it, Django has a `JSONField` field natively in 4.0

Answer (score 0):

The problem is **not from your code** it's from `django_messages` package that you installed

```
File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django_messages\apps.py", line 2
```

You can fix this bug manually by overriding the package but the bug gets back every time you install the package again (in another environment)

- My suggestion is that create a new issue for [django_messages](https://github.com/arneb/django-messages) or try to fix the bug and merge request it.
- or use django 2.2 as the author of the package mentioned in the [README](https://github.com/arneb/django-messages/blob/master/README.rst#versions) of the package.
- or use another package ...